# Div aligned to the left in Firefox

Tags: html, css

If you open my site `limitx.panamerik.net` in Google Chrome, everything works fine, but when you open it in Firefox, the CSS rule `.std` aligns the content automatically to left side. Why does it happen?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    .std { width: 90%; }
}
.std {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Change it to `display:block`. `Margin:auto` doesn't work on inline elements

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

before

```
.no-gutter.grid-col2-main       { }
```

after

```
.no-gutter.grid-col2-main       { width: 100%;}
```